# Execute Immediate on DDL Statements

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I executed the following code in Oracle Database but faced with an error of the view name does not exist. Can anyone look into it ?

```
Declare 
Stmt varchar2(2000);
Var number;
Begin
Stmt:='create or replace view emp_dept_v as select * from emp';
Execute immediate stmt;
Select count(*) into var from emp_dept_v;
Dbms_output. Put_line(var);
End;
```

I know that DDL statements are auto commited, but in this case I have to add a commit statement after the execute immediate statement to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you get is a ***compilation*** error. The `PL/SQL` will be compiled before it is executed. So during compilation, the table you try to `SELECT` will not be available. And hence the error. Only if the view name already exists, this will work. Try your `select` too as dynamic.

```
Declare 
Stmt varchar2(2000);
Var number;
Begin
Stmt:='create or replace view emp_dept_v as select * from emp';
Execute immediate stmt;

Stmt:='Select count(*) from emp_dept_v';
Execute immediate stmt into var;
Dbms_output. Put_line(var);
End;
/
```

And by the way, `DDLs` do not need a `COMMIT`;

Comment: I am good to go. But could you please provide some clarifications as why it does not work. I mean we try to retrieve the value of view after its creation in the previous line.

Comment: @Satyaki As, I mentioned, the PL/SQL dont even `compile`  when the table you select does not exist.. Any SQL inside the `EXECUTE immediate` as string will be ignored during compialtion.  Only on successful compilation, the SQL in your execute immediate will actually be executed.

Comment: Thanks for that. So why does it work when I add a commit to the code after the execute immediate ?